# How to display catagories in cms page magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

How to display all catagories in  grid format in cms page magento 2.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which we used to fetch the categories.

```
$objectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 

        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category->getId());
            $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl();
        }
```

Use this code and add wherever you want to add.

Also Grid part you can handle with the HTML and CSS as well